# Call specific chunks in a subsequent chunk in R-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a few plotting chunks in an .Rmd file.

I would like to have a chunk that calls only theses specific chunks. Example follows:

````
### Plot A
```{r 1 - PlotA}

X <- 1
y <- 5

```

### Plot B
```{r 2 - PlotB}

print(X + y)

```

### Troubleshoot
```{r 3 - TB}
X <- 8 # a modification of 'X'
# Want to call chunk "Plot B"


```
````

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after. Variables declared in `1 - PlotA` will be available in `1 - TB`; what would be the point of executing `1 - PlotA` again? Is this perhaps a typo issue? In the first chunk you define `X <- 1` (with a capital "X"), while in the third chunk you do `print(x)` (with a lower "X"). Also a side comment: It's probably a good idea to *avoid* spaces in code chunk labels.

Comment: @MauritsEvers - Yes that was a typo. The idea is having a chunk that would call lines of code or specific chunks previously called.

Comment: Hi Jack. You didn't really answer my answer. Variables defined in previous code chunks are already available in the environment of later code chunks. What would be the point of re-running an earlier code chunk concomitantly with a later one? That's what I don't understand. This seems to be more of an issue with code *design* than R markdown. Can you edit your post to give a better example/explanation of what you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: @MauritsEvers. sorry for the confusion - I did word the question in a bad way. Basically, I want to have a chunk to "trouble shoot" by changing several variables and re running a chunk. See the update - hopefully it make sense. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more of a question about code design than about R markdown.

How about the following: Create a function `complex_function` and run `complex_function` with different arguments to troubleshoot.

````
```{r define_function}
complex_function <- function(x, y) print(x + y)
```

```{r default_values}
x <- 1
y <- 5
```

```{r analysis}
complex_function(x, y)
```

### Troubleshoot
```{r trouble-shoot}
complex_function(8, y)
```
````